# eclipse ssh.terminal in mac does not cmd-c cmd-v for copy paste, nor uses alt as meta in emacs -nw

Tags: ssh, emacs, eclipse

I have installed in my macbookpro osX-10.5 the eclipse IDE, Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110301-1815. I have the RSE pluging with ssh terminal. I am very happy with eclipse and the remote server file browsing but I have the following issues:

- the remote Perl files are evaluated by my local Perl instead the Perl of the remote machine. How can I set that each remote connection uses its Perl?
- the ssh terminal does not copy/paste with cmd-c/v only with the mouse. Any solution to be able to use the keyboard?
- emacs -nw gets very confused with the line arragements and does not refresh properly unless using screen multiplexer
- And my other main question. When connecting to the remote server and using `emacs -nw`, the meta key is `ESC` and I want to have it with `alt`.  Inside the normal mac osX terminal was happening the same but there is the option of having the `alt` as `meta` key instead of `ESC`. How can I set that correctly when using eclipse ssh terminal (the properties does not allow you even to change colors.)? It is a bit slow to use `esc` instead `alt` in emacs and also my `delete` key invokes `help` :-(.